# Mesh transparency, with image but turns the transparent parts black

Tags: mesh, transparency

I'm still new to this, I have a transparent image for this mesh, but it makes the transparent parts black, any help?

[image]

[image]

only appears transparent in texture paint though I don't get it

Comment: If you are using EEVEE, scroll down in the material settings (of your transparent material) and change the _Blend Mode_ to anything other than _Opaque_.

Comment: I changed it to EEVEE, and to alpha clip blend, didn't do anything different.

Comment: Hello :). Transparent parts are interpreted as black when plugged as color. Don't forget to also plug the Alpha channel into the Alpha input :).

Comment: Thank you, It worked! :)